# select distinct user with max bill rate

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table that has userIDs and bill rates. There are multiple entries per ID with different bill rates. I want to only output the userNames corresponding with their highest bill rate.

```
ID|BillRate
1 |8.1
2 |9.4
2 |7.5
3 |7.9
3 |7.9
3 |4.6
4 |3.7
4 |9.8
```

I need the output to be like:

```
ID|BillRate
1 |8.1
2 |9.4
3 |7.9
4 |9.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select id , MAX(BillRate)
from table
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use GROUP BY and select a MAX of your BillRate, try it out in an online SQL interpreter and see what you get!